# CSS Column Groups working also for Opera

Tags: css, opera, multiple-columns

We use multi columns and wish to have some blocks which do not break inside them. In theory/future, this would work with `column-break-inside : avoid;` but for right now, we are using the common workaround:

```
.columns .block {
   display:inline-block;
}
```

However, it would not be CSS if *some* browser was not acting weird. And look, Opera displays everything in only the first column if we use the `inline-block`.

Is there a way to make this work in Opera (12.16) also?

It surprised me that over 4% of our users still use Opera.

Comment: Sorry, what is `unit-inside-column`? You make it look like it's the name of an element. Is it supposed to be class?

Comment: @MrLister It is supposed to be a class for a block element inside the columns layout. I changed to code accordingly to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to add extra markup to the HTML. I don't know if this is an option? Then the blocks can stay blocks, only the content will be inline-blocks.

```html
<main class="columns">
    <section class="block"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
        dolore magna aliqua.</span></section>
    <section class="block"><span>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
        exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat.</span></section>
    <section class="block"><span>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
        in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </span></section>
</main>
```

```css
.columns {
    display:block;
    -webkit-column-count:2;
    -moz-column-count:2;
    column-count:2;
}
.columns .block{
    display:block;
}
.columns .block > span {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

I know it looks ugly, but it works! See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/ta4S7/3/).

Comment: Great, thank you very much! And yes, it looks ugly, but hey, better than looking wrong!